# Grml-Rescueboot Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: boot, grub2

Anyone experienced something like this?

Package grml-rescueboot doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I'm doing based on http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot:

Install the package:

```
apt-get install grml-rescueboot
```

Download my pfsense iso from pfsense.org:

```
wget url;gunzip *.iso.gz
```

Then put the ISO to `/boot/grml`.

Execute update-grub, here's the output:

```
root@vultr:~# update-grub  
Generating grub configuration file ...  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-83-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-83-generic  
Found Grml ISO image: /boot/grml/debian-8.3.0-amd64-i386-netinst.iso  
Found Grml ISO image: /boot/grml/pfSense-LiveCD-2.2.6-RELEASE-i386.iso  
done
```

Here's the screenshot:

http://s12.postimg.org/wq6k98dnv/Screenshot_2016_03_22_19_22_40.png

Even tried it with Debian netinstaller, but that doesn't work either.

I tried editing `/etc/default/grub` and modify `default_grub` to a different than the default `0`, but that doesn't change the fact it doesn't boot.

I've tried this package on Ubuntu 14.04, Debian 7 and 8 at different providers (digitalocean,vultr), but these installer ISO-s don't boot.

The issue is trying to hit enter on any of the Grml entries in the grub menu in the above screenshot achieves nothing, other than returning to the grub menu with the default selection highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Grml-rescueboot is a tool to boot grml ISOs.  And the grml [website](http://grml.org/) is pretty vague about it, but it says:

> Grml is a bootable live system (Live-CD) based on Debian.

Which implies it only works for Debian ISOs that are created using grml.